# Tubular Neighborhood Theorem for $C^1$ Submanifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, manifolds

Can anyone reference/disprove the theorem in the case where the embedded submanifold is merely $C^1$ instead of smooth? I have a compact $C^1$ embedded submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$ without boundary that I want to show there exists a tubular neighborhood of (with the radius of the tube not necessarily constant). Actually, I want to be able to create one piecewise using a finite covering. Much obliged.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer to your question depends on whether you are looking for a tubular neighborhood in the general differential topological sense or the more restrictive geometric sense. The answer in the topological sense is **Yes**, but in the geometric sense the answer in general is **No**. These two conceptions may coincide for $C^2$ submanifolds, but  for $C^1$ submanifolds the construction is a bit more subtle, or non-canonical, as I will elaborate below.

A $C^1$ submanifold $M\subset R^n$ may not have any neighborhoods fibrated by normal vectors. So $C^1$ submanifolds do not in general have canonical tubular neighborhoods generated by the exponential map, and "radius" of the neighborhood does not really make sense; however, they still have a tubular neighborhood in the topological sense, i.e., a $C^1$ embedding of the normal bundle which extends that of $M$, as the zero section of the bundle. These may be constructed as follows.

The fastest way to construct a topological tubular neighborhood for $M$ is by noting that there exists a $C^1$ diffeomorphism $\phi\colon R^n\to R^n$ such that $\phi(M)$ is $C^\infty$ (e.g., see Thm. 3.6 in Chap. 2 of [Hirsch's book](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387901480)). Then $\phi(M)$ is going to have a tubular neighborhood $U$ in the standard sense, obtained by applying the inverse function theorem to the exponential map (or taking the union of all sufficiently short normal vectors), and $\phi^{-1}(U)$ yields the desired tubular neighborhood of $M$ (which will be $C^1$-diffeomorphic to the normal bundle).

An example of a $C^1$ submanifold without a neighborhood fibrated by normals may be constructed as follows. Take an ellipse in $R^2$, which is not a circle, and let $M$ be the inner parallel curve of the ellipse which passes through the foci. Then $M$ will be $C^1$, but it will not have a tubular neighborhood in the geometric sense. Indeed, the nearest point projection map into $M$ will not be one-to-one in any neighborhood of $M$.

Comment: I'd not use the expression "in geometric sense" for a tubular nbd with leaves orthogonal to the submanifold. Maybe "Riemannian sense". (But that doesn't seem to be the issue of the OP, as it is quite obvious that for  $C^1$, in general there is no tub nbd in this sense).

Comment: The term "Riemannian" here did not seem to me to be preferable to "geometric" because the question is stated in the context of the Euclidean space $R^n$, and I did not want to unduly expand the context at the risk of creating confusion. When I say "geometric" I mean involving the notion of metric.  Of course things are obvious to experts, but in my experience many people are confused about the notion of the tubular neighborhood of $C^1$ submanifolds. I was also confused about this not long ago. I do not think that standard texts such as Hirsch make this issue sufficiently clear.

Comment: This is also true, then maybe for submanifolds  of  $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ "canonical vs. non canonical" would do. (Also, the term "topological" suggests a non differentiable object)

Comment: OK, I incorporated the term canonical in the answer. Thanks.

Comment: (that was just my opinion --I didn't mean to ask you to change)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can; you don't need compactness of $N$ nor finite dimension: the key word here is *paracompactness*. I wish to do a general remark and recall some basic facts, since this seems to be a recurrent topic. Let $N$ be this embedded sumbanifold of $M$. You want a homeomorphism (maybe with more regularity and with some special feature) between the normal bundle $E$ of $N$ in $M$ and some open nbd of your submanifold $N\subset M$, that extends the natural homeomorphism $j$ between the zero-section $E_0$ of $E$, and $N$. The typical situation is that you already have some map $\Phi:E\to M$ that extends $j$ *and* which is a local homeo at any point of $E_0$ (a local condition that it is usually easy to check e.g. by the local inverse theorem), and you want to show it subordinates a global homeo between an open nbd $U$ of $E_0$ in $E$, and an open nbd $V$ of $N$ in $M$. Clearly, $\Phi$ is an open map on some nbd of $S_0$ so all you need is to have $\Phi_U$ injective on some nbd, which is not completely obvious; then you may further restrict it to an open nbd $U'$ diffeomorphic to $E$. The key lemma to get injectivity is the following topological "extension of homeomorphisms" lemma:

> **Lemma.**  Let $E$ and $F$ be paracompact spaces; let $X$ be a closed subset of $E$ and $Y$ a closed subset of $F$. Let $f:E\to F$ be a
>   continuous map such that:
>
> **(i)** $f$ is a local homeo at any $x\in X$ (meaning that for any $x\in X$ there is an open nbd $B_x$ of $x$  in $E$  such that $f(B_x)$ is open in $F$ and $f_{|B_x}:B_x\to f(B_x)$ is homeo);
>
> **(ii)** $f_{|X}:X\to Y$ is bijective (hence a homeo).
>
> Then there are open nbds $U$ of $X$ in $E$ and $V$ of $Y$ in $F$ such
>   that $f_{|U}:U\to V$ is   a homeo.

Comment: I do not follow how the "local inverse theorem" mentioned above can be applied when the manifold is only C^1, because then the exponential map will be only C^0 in general.

Comment: Dear Mohammed, of course, but I am not talking about the exponential map. Local Inverse Theorem: if the differential of a $C^1$ map is invertible in a point, the map is a local diffeo at that point- (You can find this material in any textbook) . Nor I am talking about a tubular nbd which is a foliation in *orthogonal* disks to  $N$ (it is trivial that for a $C^1$ submanifold in general this will not give a foliation: think to the graph of $|x|^{3/2}|$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$). But orthogonality of the leaves is not required for a tubular nbd.

Comment: If not the exponential map, then which map are you using here?

Comment: @MohammadGhomi At least for me, a tubular neighbourhood is any embedding of the normal bundle that extends the embedding of the submanifold. There is a contractible space of those, so it makes sense to speak of "the" tubular neighbourhood.

Comment: @DenisNardin: OK, I understand that, but how is this embedding to be constructed when the submanifold is only $C^1$? To me, that seems to be the main point of the question.

Comment: @ Mohammad Ghomi this is also as I understand the question.  In my experience, such a map $\Phi$ may come from various sources or constructions (e.g. by integrating a vector field, or even projecting some $\mathbb{R}^{n+h}$-valued map to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$: this happens in the method of characteristic lines for PDE). While in almost all these situations  the map $\Phi$ is naturally a local diffeo at points of $N$ by construction, the common problem is to restrict $\Phi$ to some smaller open nbd where it is a global diffeo.